# Where did they get all of the gum from?

Tags: plot-explanation, bill-and-teds-excellent-adventure

When the *Wyld Stallyons* in [Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_&_Ted%27s_Excellent_Adventure) have a breakdown in their time-machine, they just have all of their historical buds chew some gum and patch the antennae back together in a feat of extreme engineering that would make the *Mythbusters* proud. But where did they get all of the gum from? Never mind the ridiculous amount of it.

I don't expect an answer that explains the amount but it's definitely more than a pack. In a phone booth that is already packed to its limits like some kind of college prank, where did they get the gum to do the repairs?

Comment: They were recruited outside a convenience store

Comment: @Chcuk a Circle K to be exact. "Strange things are afoot at the Circle K."

Comment: only knew it wasn't a 7/11

Comment: They are airhead high school kids in the 80's and you're asking where they got that much gum?

Comment: Maybe they got the gum from the bottom of the phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ted has a backpack from which he produces several Chocolate Pudding tins

> **Ted:** Here is a treat to make our minor prehistoric pit stop a bit more enjoyable.

### [image]

The fact that he has enough pudding tins to share is a fair indication that he is prepared with other treats as well and it isn't much of a stretch to imagine that an air-headed high school kid from the 80's would also have several packs of bubble gum in his backpack to share as well.

So where did they get all the gum? From Ted's backpack (which is indeed along for the already crowded ride), and likely before that, the Circle K.

Answer (score -2):

The simply answer is a Deus Ex Machina. As with most movies when the hero needs a item (or knows just what to do) to save the day he/she/it will somehow have just the item needed.

Since we also have not only do Bill and Ted have a magical item, they someone have acquired cans of beans and franks. Also they have somehow acquired the knowledge to fix a future device.

Comment: I don't remember the cans of beans and franks. I may have to watch it again. The only thing is that despite being a comedy and centered on idiots it actually takes care to explain almost all of it's mechanics in general (the missing keys)

Comment: That could be a possibly that they went back in time and gave the other selves a note on how to fix the time machine with the items in their backpack.

Comment: I believe it was tins of pudding as opposed to beans & franks.